# How can I run multiple containers in circleci build?

Tags: docker, circleci

I have a node application which requires dyanmodb in AWS. I am using `amazon/dynamodb-local` container on local to test my application. I wonder whether I can set up this container in circle.ci.

Below is the configuration for circle.ci. I added a different image in `docker`. It doesn't seems to work fine. But I wonder whether it is the correct way to do. How can I make sure my code is running inside `node` container rather `dynamodb` container.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    docker:
      - image: node:12.16.2-alpine3.11
      - image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn lint
      - run: yarn test
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be late to the party and you have most probably figured this one out, but per CircleCI documentation all commands run in the Primary Container

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/glossary/#primary-container